# What is the notation for total number of rows in a matrix S?

Tags: matrices, notation

Consider a matrix S(i,j). It has n columns and m rows. How do I indicate m rows for matrix S? What is the notation?

I wish to write: d = c x (number of rows in S).

**What is the mathematical notation for the "number of rows in S" ?**

**d = c x ?.**

This is what I am looking for ..

Comment: I'm confused by your notation $d=cx$. What does it have to do with $S$? What are $d$, $c$, and $x$? I can tell you that there is no standard notation for the number of rows of a matrix given only the name of the matrix, usually you would just say $m$. You could make notation up if you want though.

Comment: If $x$ is supposed to be $\times$, then the notation would be that $S$ is an $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Do you mean $d\times c$?  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  They'll be much easier to read, and you'll get better response.

Comment: yes I mean d=c times the number of rows of matrix S ... really nobody knows this or is just no notation for it ? The times sign is to late to modify ... I can't change the content ...

Comment: so there is no standard ? I have seen one notation but it looks weird: rows(S). So my d=c x rows(S) , can this be it ?